# execute only one jmeter thread in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jmeter

1. I have a JMeter file =>Performance.jmx, containing 3 threads A, B, C.
2. I have uploaded my JMX file in Git hub.
3. Jenkins is alrady in sync with Git.
4. I need to execute only thread C for which i will set the time.

What should I do to execute only thread C?

Currently I am using -- /opt/jmeter/bin/jmeter -n -t Performance.jmx -l Performance.jtl

It executing all the threads.

Comment: You cannot execute partial test plan. Create separate test plans(.jmx files) for each thread.

Comment: @Sanghamitra Dash, You mean thread group, rt?  If you mean thread, this question does not make any sense to me!!

Answer (score 1):

You can "disable" unwanted thread groups by setting number of threads to zero. To do so make a little update to your test plan using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like

1. For Thread Group A: set Number of Threads to `${__P(A_THREADS,)}`
2. For Thread Groups B and C similarly set Number of Threads to `${__P(B_THREADS,)}` and `${__P(C_THREADS,)}`
3. Execute your test as follows:

   ```
    /opt/jmeter/bin/jmeter -JA_THREADS=0 _JB_THREADS=0 -JC_THREADS=1 -n -t Performance.jmx -l Performance.jtl
   ```

Above line will execute only Thread Group C with 1 thread. If you need more - set C_THREADS property to be higher.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for comprehensive information on JMeter properties and more use cases.